# Set Text Color and Text Next to Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, input, styles

How do I set the text color (and text) next to a checkbox?

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="idCheckbox1" onClick="myCheckbox('idCheckbox1')" value=1><label>Checkbox 1</label></input></div>
<script>
function myCheckbox(idCheckbox)
{
    var ctlCheckbox = document.getElementById(idCheckbox);
    var ctlCheckText = ctlCheckbox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[0];
    var text = ctlCheckText.innerText;

    if (true == ctlCheckbox.checked)
        alert('checked');
    else
        alert('not checked');
    if (ctlCheckbox.checked == true)
       ctlCheckText.innerText = 'smurfs';
    else
       ctlCheckText.InnerText = 'gargamel';
}
</script>
```

Searching the internet helped a bit. I am able to get the text, and determine the check state, however setting the color or changing the text more than initially does not work.

I want to set the text blue, so I was thinking the following, which does not work, annoyingly so.

```
 if (true == ctlCheckbox.checked)
     ctlCheckText.innerHTML = '<span style="color:#0000FF">' + text + '</span>';
 else
     ctlCheckText.innerHTML = '<span style="color:#000000">' + text + '</span>';
```

Thoughts?

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G21HM18SJQIC) is a sample project, which I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of setting inline style use a class and then depending of the status of `checkbox` `add` or `remove` the class `blue` from `classList`

Also instead of `if (ctlCheckbox.checked == true)` you can use only `if (ctlCheckbox.checked)` since it will be evaluated to true, but if you still want to use then use `===` instead of `==` that is `if (ctlCheckbox.checked === true)`

```js
function myCheckbox(idCheckbox) {
  var ctlCheckbox = document.getElementById(idCheckbox);
  var ctlCheckText = ctlCheckbox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[0];
  var text = ctlCheckText.innerText;

  if (ctlCheckbox.checked) {
    ctlCheckText.innerHTML = 'smurfs';
    ctlCheckText.classList.add('blue')

  } else {
    ctlCheckText.innerHTML = 'gargamel';
    if (ctlCheckText.classList.contains('blue')) {
      ctlCheckText.classList.remove('blue')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="idCheckbox1" onClick="myCheckbox('idCheckbox1')" value='1'><label>Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew, but forgot about the ===, have to refresh my knowledge of that. I had no clue on the classList stuff, thanks. I will need to look into that too. I had a type, `InnerHTML` instead of 'innerHTML` in my else clause, which is why I was never able to get `Gargamel` showing. Works great, thanks!